# python argparse voluntary part/delimeter

Tags: argparse

I just started with python3, and im using argparse lib for parsing argument list from the console input. I have studied manual at python page and searched a lot sadly i didnt found right answer:

How to correctly parse an argument,which has voluntary part separated by other character then space. Let me explain on example:

*--argument=**file.txt*** (without space after =)
I want to know when the argument has been used, and whats his 'file.txt' part(which can change).Is there some form of substitution for voluntary part?

parser.add_argument('--argument=*',action=...) #or so..

--Thanks

p.s. Sadly alternative with space is not an option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`argparse` handles a `=` joining flag and argument:

```
parser.add_argument('--argument',help='your help line here')
```

This will accept either.

```
'--argument=file.txt'
'--argument file.txt'
```

The default is to expect one value `nargs=None`.  If not given the default value is `None`.

See

```
16.4.4.1
For long options (options with names longer than a single character), the option and 
value can also be passed as a single command-line argument, using = to separate them:

>>> parser.parse_args('--foo=FOO'.split())
Namespace(foo='FOO', x=None)
```

Without the `--`, the argument is `positional`

```
parser.add_argument('argument',help='your help line here')
```

I assume by 'voluntary' you mean 'optional' (as used in the documentation).  But now is required.  That is, you'll get an error if you don't provide the filename.